# C# Epoch time to date and timezone convertion

Tags: c#, timezone, epoch

what is good way to convert Epoch time to date, but using specific timezone

I need to check two dates. One date i have in database and another in x website.

I know that both dates are exactly the same in relation of yyyy-MM-dd

**in example:**

**Database date is:** 1398891600 = 2014-05-01

**X Website date is:** 1398902400000 = 2014-05-01

C# code "converter"

```
private string DateChecker_inEPOCH(string epochdate)
        {
            if (epochdate.Length < 13)
            {
                epochdate = epochdate + "000";
            }
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(epochdate));

            string dateFormated = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            return dateFormated;

        }
```

Issue is that when i convert using my method one db date is 2014-04-30 and website date is 2014-05-01.

I tested dates using http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: *nitpick:* Please don't call it "epoch time".  That's a misuse of the dictionary word *epoch*.  See [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epoch) 2, 3, or 5a.  The *epoch* in this case is the "unix epoch" of 1970-01-00 00:00:00 UTC - not the value you're evaluating against it.  See also [Notable epoch dates in computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Database date is: 1398891600 = 2014-05-01
>
> X Website date is: 1398902400000 = 2014-05-01

EpochConverter.com gives me the following results:

1398891600000 -> Wed, 30 Apr 2014 21:00:00 GMT

1398902400000 -> Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00 GMT

So your code seems to be consistent with EpochConverter.com.

With regards to timezones, I would make sure all dates are stored/retrieved using UTC. This will save you a lot of headaches when it comes to converting to/from different timezones. In this case, assuming the epoch was stored relative to a UTC date, you would simply do the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(Convert.ToDouble(epochdate));
```

You can then use the following if you need to display a local time to the end user:

```
utcDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Yes but im on +3 GMT and if you add 3 hrs to DB time you will get correct date ;)

Comment: Sounds like the timestamp from the website is in a non-UTC format. This is where things start to get messy. Is that anything you have control over?

Comment: More likely, the timestamp that was in the db was not taken from UTC, but from the server's time zone (`DateTime.Now` vs. `DateTime.UtcNow`).